# How to keep the multi dimensional array list in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am doing automation for my app. Here I am selecting a particular game..
here list array contain  9 data .. like I am fetch gui data and put it into array... how to write better way to select a game ?
fetch data from oracle db code :

```
game_date=result.getString(1);
home_team_name=result.getString(2);
away_team_name=result.getString(3);




WebElement listView = AppSession.findElementByAccessibilityId("ListView1");
List<WebElement> row = listView.findElements(By.tagName("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'item')]"));
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> outerList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> innerList = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int a = 0; a < row.size(); a++) {
    List<WebElement> column = row.get(a).findElements(By.tagName("./*[contains(@LocalizedControlType, 'text')]"));
    for (int j = 0; j < column.size(); j++) //take first column
    {
        innerList.add(column.get(j).getAttribute("Name"));
    }
}
outerList.add(innerList);
System.out.println(innerList);
System.out.println(innerList.size());//9
System.out.println(outerList);
System.out.println(outerList.size()); //1
for (int i = 0; i < outerList.size(); i++) {
    if ((outerList.get(i).contains(game_date)) && (outerList.get(i).contains(home_team_name)) && (outerList.get(i).contains(away_team_name))) {
        WebElement line_up1 = AppSession.findElementByName(game_date);
        line_up1.click();
    }
}
```

this is how my gui app looks like for game selection...

> ```
>  Game date                   home team             away team
>     06/29/2018 07:00:00 PM     Ball Hogs Ball Hogs    Tri-State Tri-State
>     06/29/2018 08:00:00 PM     Power                  Ghost BALLERS
>     06/29/2018 07:00:00 PM     Killer 3's             3's Company
> ```

if i can use inner array  list. it is better way to write ..

My expected output of outer list should be like this ::

```
[[06/29/2018 07:00:00 PM ,Ball Hogs Ball Hogs ,Tri-State Tri-State],[06/29/2018 08:00:00 PM, Power, Ghost BALLERS],[06/29/2018 07:00:00 PM, Killer 3's, 3's Company]]
```

I am getting outerlist loop like this ::

```
[06/29/2018 07:00:00 PM ,Ball Hogs Ball Hogs ,Tri-State Tri-State,06/29/2018 08:00:00 PM, Power, Ghost BALLERS,06/29/2018 07:00:00 PM, Killer 3's, 3's Company]
```

I want to take the  entire data in the first  row of GUI as index 1 and so i can take 3 index and loop that index and check the game and click...

Comment: TLDR; *How to keep the multi dimensional array list in java* either YourType[][] or List<List<YourType>>

Comment: @Antoniossss  List<List<YourType>>  please check my question.. I want to take outerlist index as 3..but here print as 1..